# The Sum of FFT of direct and reversed signal

Tags: signal-processing, fft, frequency-analysis

Is there a similarity between the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) of a signal and the FFT of the same signal reversed in time, i.e.

```
FFT(Sig_direct=[1 2 3 4 5])
FFT(Sig_reversed=[5 4 3 2 1])
```

Also, I would like to know if the summing up of the two spectra (direct and reversed) helps to maximize the information in terms of low-frequency components?

Answer (score 4):

Flipping the time signal flips the frequency response (around the zero frequency), see for example [here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html) for a proof.

Thus, if you signal is real-valued, then reversing it causes the sign of the imaginary component of the FFT to flip (because of the complex conjugate symmetry in the frequency domain).

Summing up the spectra would thus cancel out the imaginary component -- with disastrous consequences. Note that summing of spectra is the same as summing the signals, because the Fourier transform is linear: F(a+b) = F(a)+F(b). What would happen to your signal if you add the reversed signal to it? The same kind of destruction happens to the frequency spectrum if you add the two. It would not at all help you get a better view of your low frequency components, if you're unlucky these components might even be completely canceled out. Here's an example of that happening: I create a signal that is two periods of the sine function. Then I compute the FFT of the signal and its reversed version. The sum of these is spectra is 0 everywhere (actually slightly different from zero due to numerical rounding errors):

```matlab
t = linspace(0,4*pi,128);
f1 = sin(t);
f2 = flip(f1);
F1 = fft(f1);
F2 = fft(f2);
k = 0:length(t)-1;
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(k,abs(F1))
set(gca,'xlim',[0,127],'ylim',[0,70])
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(k,abs(F2))
set(gca,'xlim',[0,127],'ylim',[0,70])
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(k,abs(F1+F2))
set(gca,'xlim',[0,127],'ylim',[0,70])
```

Here is the output: top two plots are the magnitudes of the two spectra (both identical), bottom plot is the magnitude of the sum (zero everywhere):

[image: output of code above]

However, adding the magnitudes of the frequency components would be possible. The result would be identical if you were to just multiply the frequency spectrum by 2 -- so no improvement is possible this way.

Reviewing [the paper you linked in the comment](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322844529_Efficient_Conversion_of_Deep_Features_to_Compact_Binary_Codes_using_Fourier_Decomposition_for_Multimedia_Big_Data), it seems to me that these authors are using the FFT without understanding what they are doing. What is more, their equations do not match their description of what they're doing, making me believe they are not very well versed in mathematics either. Note that Ff and Fb in their Algorithm 2 are identical: the only difference is that the summation is reversed, but the elements being summed over are identical. Since the sum is independent of the order of the summands, nothing changes by reversing the order of the summation. The equation for Fb does not represent the FFT of the reversed signal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but i have seen identical approch from an article (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322844529_Efficient_Conversion_of_Deep_Features_to_Compact_Binary_Codes_using_Fourier_Decomposition_for_Multimedia_Big_Data); please see algorithm 2.

Comment: @Riadelectro: See the update to the answer, I've added a simple experiment that demonstrates why this is a bad idea.